# Create a multilines Readme.txt with R

Tags: r, shiny, readme

I would like to create a txt file with multiple lines. Being a problem much asked, I found several solutions (like "\ n" etc ...) but none seems to work in my case and I do not understand why. Whatever I do, my text is only displayed on one line. Here is what I tried :

```
Readme <- file("Readme.txt", "w")
writeLines("____________________________", Readme, sep = "")
writeLines("\n")
writeLines("  SEN2EXTRACT APPLICATION", Readme, sep = "")
writeLines("\n")
writeLines("____________________________", Readme, sep = "")
writeLines("\n")
writeLines("Sen2extract is a shiny application allowing you to extract 
           time series of spectral indexes on your study sites.", Readme, sep = "")
close(Readme)
```

**Desired display :**

> ---
>
> ```
>  SEN2EXTRACT APPLICATION
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Sen2extract is a shiny application allowing you to extract time series
>   of spectral indexes on your study sites.

**Obtained result :**

> ____________________________  SEN2EXTRACT APPLICATION____________________________Sen2extract is a shiny
>   application allowing you to extract 
>                  time series of spectral indexes on your study sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have removed the usual new line characters from `writeLines` when writing to the file by changing `sep`. Then it looks like you want to add new lines separately but you are not writing these to the file, just the console.

Comment: Well, even with the default function, it's displayed on one line for me: `fileConn<-file("output.txt")
    writeLines(c("first line","second line", "third line"), fileConn)
    close(fileConn)`

Comment: @Grits What OS are you using?

Comment: My application is running on a Ubuntu 18.04 server. And I receive my .txt on Windows 7

Comment: There may be a difference in newline conventions causing the issue then. You could try setting `sep="\r\n"` to see if that helps.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much @James. You were very helpful !